# how can iterate and unpack properly the information in a Java Object Matrix

Tags: java, arrays, object, matrix, iterator

I have to iterate and implement a simple logic on object like this:

```
public static final Object [][]matrix = {  
    {integerValue,"description"},
    {integerValue, "description"} ,
    ....
    ....
};
```

and this is a little (and wrong) example of operations that i have to do:

```
for(Object element : matrix) {
    if(stringToCompare == stringInTheCurrentElement) {
        return respectiveIntegerValue;
    }
}
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to iterate over the bi-dimensional array:

```
for (Object[] obj : matrix) {
    Integer currentInteger = (Integer) obj[0];
    String currentDescription = (String) obj[1];
    if (stringToCompare.equals(currentDescription)) {
        return currentInteger;
    }
}
```